# How to enable illegal characters in filenames on windows 10?

Tags: windows, filesystems

I'm trying to create files with names such as: asterisk, pipe, uppercase letters and lowercase letters but Windows doesn't allow me for that. Is there command for enabling such feature? I'm using NTFS file system.

I tried using WSL and it didn't work, when I tried creating file using `touch a.txt` and `touch A.txt` and it didn't create second file named `A.txt`.

Comment: NTFS is case-insensitive and certain characters are simply illegal. 
 See [Naming Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#naming-conventions).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it for at least these forbidden characters `\ / : * ? " < > |`. Window by default will not allow you to do that by any means.